# How can I migrate a product from an agilefant installation to another one?

Tags: project-management, agile, data-migration

We have an internal installation of Agilefant. We are done with the first sprint and already started the second one now our client asked access to Agilefant so he can check our progress. The problem is that we have multiple projects inside of our installation and we don't want them to see the other projects:) You can understand that:)

If I'm right you cannot restrict an Agilefant user to have access only for one product, he will see all of them (please correct if I'm wrong).

So the solution is to make another installation and somehow migrate the project to that installation. Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm open for other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a great answer for my question from [jarno](http://agilefant.freeforums.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=2) a site administrator on the Agilefant Community Forum. There are no easy ways to achieve a product's migration yet. Although  jarno described two ways how you can do it:

a) You can take a copy of your database, put it into another Agilefant instance and delete all products that you don't need. Then you can create users for your client.

b) You can adopt Agilefant 3.0 alpha X. You will be able to restrict product access based on teams with Agilefant 3.0 alpha X!

You can find more details and known issues with this version of Agilefant on the link below:

http://agilefant.freeforums.org/how-can-i-migrate-a-product-from-an-agilefant-installation-t205.html

Comment: Answering only with a link is considered bad practice in SO. Could you edit your answer and provide at least the core of the answer here?